# How to select text while using Find Next?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, find, selection

I am trying to edit a document.  There are large chunks of data that I want to delete.  I know the starting point of the chunk, and I know the last word of the chunk.  Those are invariable.  But the amount of text in between is variable.  I would like to do something like kick off a select, then press Find to find the last word of the selection.  Then I can just delete it with one press of the delete button.  But I cannot find a way to do this.  I am hoping someone can come up with an easy way.

Comment: If looking for Xyz, at start of delete area do a ctrl-f for XYZ. It should highlight all the XYZ terms in the document. Hold the shift key down. Then arrow down or page down until find the ending XYZ and delete.

Comment: Not sure this would work, because the beginning word is different from the ending word.  Perhaps I should have used a different word to describe it than 'invariable.'  What I meant to imply is that the first word is always the same. and the last word is always the same, but they aren't equal to each other.

Comment: Does these words occur only once in your document?

Comment: As long as there is a starting location, this works. I was not saying XYZ had to both at the beginning and the end, just at the end. If the delete section starts with ABC, go to ABC, do the ctrl-f for only highlighting XYZ, it is not used for movement.  Try it out and see if this will do.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  No, that's not what I am saying that I want to do.  Holding the shift key and arrowing down to the final word is the easy part.  I can do that without the highlighting.
What I would like is this:
Place cursor at beginning word.  
Do some keystrokes or whatever so that when I press ctrl-f to find the next word, the entire section of text is highlighted, from the beginning word to the found ending word.
Press delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards to select the text you desire:

- press CTRL+H
- press "More >>>"
- Check "use wildcards"
- use "find what": `firstWord*LastWord`, where FirstWord and LastWord are the words at the beginning and end of your desired text.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  That just may work for what I need!  That's a really cool trick to know!